# IN EAN API of Booking reservation giving error as TravelNow.com cannot service this request.Authentication failure

Tags: api

While using ENA API of hotel reservation , error is coming as

1RECOVERABLEAUTHENTICATION-1TravelNow.com cannot service this request.Authentication failure. (cid=0; ipAddress=114.143.96.23; sig=28f6ba17b4ba1d9e4c898e21c2be8802 ; time=1400160329; server=65)0ABAAA41-712E-3914-6002-0DB253901793" -1RECOVERABLEAUTHENTICATION-1TravelNow.com cannot service this request.Authentication failure. (cid=0; ipAddress=114.143.96.23; sig=28f6ba17b4ba1d9e4c898e21c2be8802 ; time=1400160329; server=65)0ABAAA41-712E-3914-6002-0DB253901793

you can refer this link : http://developer.ean.com/apitester/

Comment: Aside from the fact you've given us basically nothing, you have your answer in your error message. It didn't authenticate properly

Comment: yes , am passing proper parameter still am getting error is TravelNow.com cannot service this request.Authentication failure..

sig = md5($apiKey . $secret . $timestamp);

Answer (score 1):

Expedia has endpoint problem with http://api.ean.com, Meantime we need to use http://dev.api.ean.com/ in our request call.

For example:

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccity%3ESeattle%3C%2Fcity%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CstateProvinceCode%3EWA%3C%2FstateProvinceCode%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CcountryCode%3EUS%3C%2FcountryCode%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CarrivalDate%3E4%2F19%2F2015%3C%2FarrivalDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CdepartureDate%3E4%2F21%2F2015%3C%2FdepartureDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRoomGroup%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C%2FnumberOfAdults%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoomGroup%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CnumberOfResults%3E25%3C%2FnumberOfResults%3E%0A%3C%2FHotelListRequest%3E
```

will become

```
http://dev.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccity%3ESeattle%3C%2Fcity%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CstateProvinceCode%3EWA%3C%2FstateProvinceCode%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CcountryCode%3EUS%3C%2FcountryCode%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CarrivalDate%3E4%2F19%2F2015%3C%2FarrivalDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CdepartureDate%3E4%2F21%2F2015%3C%2FdepartureDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRoomGroup%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C%2FnumberOfAdults%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoomGroup%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CnumberOfResults%3E25%3C%2FnumberOfResults%3E%0A%3C%2FHotelListRequest%3E
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.hurl.it/ to test API.

I was facing the same problem ,i found that problem was with sig value,however,i was passing false sig value.
Check http://developer.ean.com/md5-hash-generator to generate sig value.